# Subfigure is not working fine into a beamer presentation -

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats, subfloats, presentations

I have this in the preamble ...

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}


\begin{document}
```

and in a frame I have

```
\begin{frame}{Experimento y análisis de resultados}
\vspace{0pt}
\begin{figure}[ht!] % fl1400

\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.10\textwidth} %1 MODS
    \includegraphics[ height= 2cm, width=\textwidth]{Rfl1400MODS}
    \caption{{\scriptsize MODS}}
    \label{fig:MODS}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.10\textwidth} %2 EMODS
    \includegraphics[height= 2cm,width=0.10\textwidth]{Rfl1400EMODS.eps}
    \caption{{\scriptsize EMODS}}
    \label{fig:EMODS}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{0pt}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.10\textwidth} %3 SAMODS
    \includegraphics[height= 2cm,width=\textwidth]{Rfl1400SAMODS.eps}
    \caption{{\scriptsize SAMODS}}
    \label{fig:SAMODS}
\end{subfigure}
\vspace{0pt}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.10\textwidth} %4 SAGAMODS
    \includegraphics[height= 2cm,width=\textwidth]{Rfl1400SAGAMODS}
    \caption{{\scriptsize SAGAMODS} }
    \label{fig: SAGAMODS}
\end{subfigure}
\vspace{0pt}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.10\textwidth} %5 PARMODS
    \includegraphics[height= 2cm,width=\textwidth]{Rfl1400PARMODS}
    \caption{{\scriptsize PARMODS}}
    \label{fig:PARMODS}
\end{subfigure}    
\caption{Resultados para fl1400}
\label{fig:Resultados para fl1400}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

it it's showing only the image 1 and 4 of the 5 images, images 2, 3 and 5 are not showing up

Comment: Notice that you are using `width=0.10\textwidth` for the second image, which is printed inside a minipage od width `0.10\textwidth`, so the actual width of image 2 is `0.01\textwidth` so you will hardly see it. Besides that, except for some alignment issues I can't reproduce the problem mentioned for images 3 and 5. Would it be possible for you to upload elsewhere the actual images you use so we can test with the actual images?

Comment: Why are you using floats for a slide presentation?

Comment: @JohnKormylo, probably for the labellings..?

Comment: You don't need \caption to label a figure.  In fact, one can almost always get better results using tabular instead of subfigure.